# Select correct row in Access Dropdown in vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a drop down box in a Microsoft Access form. The columns appear in this order:

Field0, Field1, Field2, CompanyName, CompanyID

I am attempting to extract the value of the CompanyID column depending on the selection in the drop down. It happens that there are multiple rows containing the same company name. No matter which row I select containing a given CompanyName, the following code always extracts the value of the CompanyID column in the first of the rows, not the selected one. I need to modify the code to select the proper row, and don't know the row until selected by the user.

MyDropDown.Column(4)

Comment: Well, that should work. Where are you using that reference? Is BoundColumn property set to column 5?

Comment: I'm using this in vba trying to use the selected row's CompanyID field in a process. I also interrogated the ListIndex property, and it is returning the first row out of all containing the same CompanyName, no matter which I pick.  It also does not seem to matter which is the bound column.

Comment: Multiple rows with same company name but the CompanyID is different? Why? I cannot replicate the issue. My code returns the CompanyID of selected row. Edit question to post your code.